# how to copy excel sheet into another sheet and send it via email

Tags: vba, email, excel

I am working on a project where user will fill the information and when click on a send button the exact file will be mailed to some other person with new name

here is my code which works fine to send an email

```
    Sub send_email_via_Gmail()
Dim myMail As CDO.Message

Set myMail = New CDO.Message

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "example@gmail.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

With myMail
.Subject = "Test Email from Dr. Takyar"
.From = "example@gmail.com"
.To = "example1@gmail.com"

.TextBody = "Good morning!"

End With

myMail.Send
MsgBox ("Mail has been sent")
Set myMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

and this is code which will make exact replica of existing sheet

```
   Sub Add_Sheet()
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = InputBox("New Name:")
End Sub
```

now my problem is how do i make new workbook instead of worksheet and send them via email

Here is My code

```
Sub Add_Sheet()

Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.add
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Data\SalesData1.xlsx"
       Workbooks("SalesData1.xlsx").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: For copying the sheet to a new workbook, just use `ActiveSheet.Copy` withouth the `After:...` part. For more on CDO message sending, see this: [http://rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm](http://rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm) To add an attachment, you can use the `myMail.AddAttachment "C:\path..."` method.

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of trouble i finally found the solution 
here is the code which clone the worksheet and send it via gmail and 
 is totally working on excel -2007 - 2010 - 2013

```
      Sub Copy_Every_Sheet_To_New_Workbook()
     'Working in 97-2013
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Mail As New Message
    Dim name As String
    Dim Config As Configuration
    Dim fileName As String
Set Config = Mail.Configuration

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Copy every sheet from the workbook with this macro
    Set Sourcewb = ThisWorkbook

    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & Sourcewb.name & " " & DateString
    fileName = Sourcewb.name & " " & DateString
    MkDir FolderName

    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets

        'If the sheet is visible then copy it to a new workbook
        If sh.Visible = -1 Then
            sh.Copy

            'Set Destwb to the new workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2013
                    If Sourcewb.name = .name Then
                        MsgBox "Your answer is NO in the security dialog"
                        GoTo GoToNextSheet
                    Else
                        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        Case 52:
                            If .HasVBProject Then
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                            Else
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
            End With

            'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
            If Destwb.Sheets(1).ProtectContents = False Then
                With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
                    .Cells.Copy
                    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Cells(1).Select
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If


            'Save the new workbook and close it
            With Destwb
                .SaveAs FolderName _
                      & "\" & fileName & FileExtStr, _
                        FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
                .Close False
            End With



        End If
GoToNextSheet:
    Next sh
    MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
MsgBox FolderName & "\" & ActiveSheet.name & ".xlsm"
Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 465
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = "example@gmail.com"

Config(cdoSendPassword) = "password"
Config.Fields.Update

Mail.To = "example1@gmail.com"
Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
Mail.Subject = "hhhhhhhhhhhhh"
Mail.AddAttachment FolderName & "\" & fileName & ".xlsm"
Mail.HTMLBody = "fffff"
Mail.Send

MsgBox "sent "

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With  
End Sub
```